# XSD. Construction of shema

Tags: xml, xsd

mates!
I have the following issue.
I try to make XSD scheme: I have the object "Task", that may be either teoretical or practical.
Tasks have implementation phase satus. Teoretical and practical tasks have different statuses.
I need to prevent situation when teoretical task have practical status for example.
Can you give some advice or maybe hint for better way to resolve it than to make different objects "Practical_task" and "Teoretical_task".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define two elements theoreticalTask and practicalTask with different type definitions, both belonging to a substitution group headed by an abstract element named task.

Comment: Thank you, I agree absolutely with this decision.